# PHPMotion install at xampp give a blank screen

Tags: xampp

When I install PHPMotion using XAMPP 1.7.3, there is nothing - a blank screen. What should I do in order to find if it is the PHPMotion is not working or the XAMPP is not working?

Answer (score 1):

In PHPMotion package, there is a component PHPShield, which takes as a loader, unfortunately these components only for Linux. As for the version of Windows is not included in the package because it's not free (see http://www.phpshield.com/).

Alternatively, you may be able to download the [PHPShield for Windows](http://www.phpshield.com/loaders/phpshield.loaders.windows.zip)

Extract the file, then copy to folder `xampp\php\ext`

Edit the `php.ini` file and add the line `extension="phpshield.5.2.win"`

Then restart apache